# C, having compile issues when using sqrt and math.h

Tags: c, libraries

For a class I need to turn in a file in which I use math.h's sqrt method. For some reason this does not compile properly unless I use the -lm flag to link the program to my file. The class will be compiling my code without using the -lm flag so I was wondering if there is anyway to make this work without using the -lm flag.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use functions from `math.h`.

Comment: "The class will be compiling my code without using the -lm flag". It's wrong. Complain.

Comment: @n.m. - It isn't wrong if the OP isn't meant to use those functions yet. I recall a class half way through the first semester that had us implement a very basic `sqrt` ourselves. Naturally using `math.h` would have defeated the purpose of the exercise. So not linking with `libm` is a decent way to enforce a certain goal.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then OP should have been given instructions not to use `<math.h>`. -lm is an implementation detail not needed on all systems.

Comment: @n.m. - The OP knows what environment their code is to be tested on. They were told in advanced, as well as the constraints under which their code will compile.  This is not an oversight due to an implementation detail (I lay such complaints before my own instructors once, that was the answer).

Comment: @StoryTeller "This is not an oversight due to an implementation detail" An instructor relying on implementation details of the in-class environment is much worse than as a student relying on implementation details of their at-home environment. Setting bad example. If the student is not supposed to use functions from math.h, an appropriate instruction would be "don't use functions from math.h". Simple, gets to the point, tells the whole story.

Comment: @n.m. - Well, that's your opinion, and you are entitled to it. But IMHO there are pedagogical advantages to laying implicit requirements for students to figure out. One won't have *most* of the standard library on a free-standing environment, should one expect it to be spelled out to them then as well!?

Comment: @StoryTeller I think one should teach stiudents to work with documentation. Figuring out implicit requirements is something they will pick up on their own, all too quickly.

Comment: Is it a *requirement* (e.g. in your assessment specs, which we can't see) that you use `sqrt` from `<math.h>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways around using `math.h` to find the square root of a number. There are iterative methods such as *Newton's Method* (and all it's variations, e.g. *Newton-Raphson*, etc.), Taylor Series approximations and so on. But there are some very fast, very accurate specific implementations for finding the square root (or inverse square root) that are available.

One such implementation is the [**Fast Inverse Square Root**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) attributed to John Carmack (with some dispute). While it finds the inverse square root in the original form, taking the inverse to find the square root is trivial.

Here are two functions (one for `float` and one for `double`) that you can implement without `math.h`. The amazing part is that by using the particular *floating-point* constant, you can achieve impressive precision in a function that will generally converge in 3-5 iterations. Give them a try:

```
/** John Carmack's, Fast Inverse Square Root (square-root version).
 *  generally converges within 3 iterations
 *  see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
 */
float sqrt_fisr (float x)
{
    float tmp, xhalf = 0.5f * x;
    size_t n_terms = 10;
    union {
        float f;
        int i;
    } u;
    u.f = x;
    u.i = 0x5f3759df - (u.i >> 1);

    u.f *= 1.5f - xhalf * u.f * u.f;
    while (n_terms-- && u.f != (tmp = u.f * (1.5f - xhalf * u.f * u.f)))
        u.f = tmp;

    return 1.0f / u.f;
}
```

and if needed with type `double`, you can use the following, but **note** in enforces 64-bit integers using the `uint64_t` type (found in `stdint.h`),

```
/** John Carmack's Fast Inverse Square Root (square-root double).
 *  generally converges within 3 iterations
 *  see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
 */
double sqrtd_fisr (double x)
{
    double tmp, xhalf = 0.5d * x;
    size_t n_terms = 10;
    union {
        double d;
        uint64_t i;
    } u;
    u.d = x;
    u.i =  0x5fe6eb50c7b537a9 - (u.i >> 1);

    u.d *= 1.5d - xhalf * u.d * u.d;
    while (n_terms-- && u.d != (tmp = u.d * (1.5d - xhalf * u.d * u.d)))
        u.d = tmp;

    return 1.0d / u.d;
}
```

**note:** above the `union` is used to allow entry of the *"floating-point constant"* in integer form and provides a simple method for the syntactically legal use of the same bits (either 32 in case of `float` or `64` in the case of `double`) as either an integer or floating-point representation of the value in memory without the use of casts that may run afoul of the *strict-aliasing rule*.

There are links in the Wikipedia page discussing the development of the *"magic numbers"* used in the computation that are a fairly interesting read.

Answer (score 0):

The math.h header declares functions that are implemented in the library that is linked with -lm. If you cannot link with -lm, then you cannot use functions from math.h. So, as @StoryTeller has commented:

> Don't use functions from `math.h`

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had same problems, made many tries with those linker flags, where changing order of lib (none of these tries worked). So I just implemented Newtons square root method. Link: [Square root of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

It is not hard to make cubic root or higher levels root calculation function with Newtons method.:)

Here is simple prototype:

```
double sqaure_root_of(double value){
double  s1 = 0;
double  q1 = 0;
uint8_t cnt = 0;
uint8_t digit_num = 0;
uint32_t value1 = (uint32_t)value;

while(value1 != 0){
    value1 = value1/10;
    digit_num++;
}
if((value > 0)&&(value < 1)){
    digit_num = 10;
}

if(value <= 0)
    return 0;

s1 = value/2;
printf("s1: %f\r\n",s1);
while(cnt < digit_num*2){
    q1 = s1*s1;
    q1 = q1-value;
    q1 = q1/(2*s1);
    q1 = s1-q1;
    cnt++;
    s1 = q1;
}
return q1;
```

}